# Vary the build output path depending on the current OS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cross-platform, .net-6.0

I'm currently working on my first .NET 6 cross-plattform project in VisualStduio 2022.
I want to change my build output (Base output path) to: `..\..\..\bin\`.
I know that this only works for windows.
Is there a way to adjust this path so it works for both windows and unix?

I tried this and it only works for windows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsWindows Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true'">true</IsWindows>
  <IsLinux Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))' == 'true'">true</IsLinux>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsWindows)'=='true'">   
  <BaseOutputPath>..\..\..\bin\</BaseOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(IsLinux)'=='true'">
  <BaseOutputPath>../../../bin/</BaseOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In my project.cs I would use:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName;
```

but not sure how to use it in the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild v15 and later has a `NormalizeDirectory` function that will ensure the correct directory separator for the current OS. (See "[MSBuild property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-property-functions)".) Your code can be changed to the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseOutputPath>$([MSBuild]::NormalizeDirectory('..\..\..\bin\'))</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In ItemGroups, MSBuild handles mapping paths based on the OS. In the following example the `Include` paths are equivalent, interchangeable, and work on both Windows and Unix.

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Windows Include="..\..\..\bin\*.*" />
      <Unix    Include="../../../bin/*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

If for other reasons you need to know the current OS is Unix, use the `IsOSUnixLike` function.

```
    <Message Text="Hello Windows" Condition="!$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())" />
    <Message Text="Hello *nix"    Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSUnixLike())" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking exactly for this.
Also thanky you for the link to the MSBuild documentation!